# How to pop the current page in xamarin forms?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, navigation, xamarin.forms

I've created the Xamarin forms project. I have created the master detail page and the other pages. I want to pop the current page so that I can go back to the previous page. I've used the below code:

```
await Navigation.PopAsync();
```

This works in Android but sometimes it crashes the iOS app in strange behaviour. When I move around in the app then in many pages sometimes when the PopAsync is called the content is removed and page goes blank but the page don't get back to the previous page and when I press he back button the app crashes. I've tried to catch the error but the error comes (null).
How can I pop the page then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution. it was due to the custom renderer in the iOS of list view. I deleted the custom renderer and it worked